# Why is no current flowing through this resistance?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Why is no current flowing through the 25 Ω resistance?
[image]

This is the circuit before short-circuiting (a)(b):
[image]

Comment: It is in parallel with a wire, which has zero resistance.

Comment: Ah my bad , in that wire there was a voltage controlled voltage source by the voltage of the resistance, it was 3v but now they said no current goes through the resistance so v=0 thus the VCVS disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, applying the [current divider formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider) to the \$25\space\Omega\$ resistor and setting the resistance in the short-circuit equal to \$\text{R}\$ we can see that the current trough the \$25\space\Omega\$ resistor is given by:

$$\text{I}_{25\space\Omega}=\frac{\text{R}}{25+\text{R}}\cdot\text{I}_\text{i}\tag1$$

Where \$\text{I}_\text{i}\$ is the current flowing towards the two parallel resistances.

The resistance of a short circuit is equal to \$\text{R}=0\space\Omega\$, so we end up with:

$$\text{I}_{25\space\Omega}=\frac{0}{25+0}\cdot\text{I}_\text{i}=0\space\text{A}\tag2$$

Comment: nice best answer thank you!

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI Thanks and you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

> *why is no current flowing through the 25 ohm resistance?*

Because it's shorted out by the wire to the right: -

[image]

Comment: i dont understand , can you please explain more

Comment: but why does it steal all the current?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI, what is the potential difference between two points on an ideal wire?

Comment: @ThePhoton zero because they have the same potential? aaaaaaaaa i see now but in our case the b's node is connected to the ground terminal or something else so the potential at b isnt the same as a's potential?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI, on the contrary, when you connect a wire between `a` and `b`, then you ensure that those points **are** at the same potential.

Answer (score 0):

When a short circuit is parallel to a  component all current flows though that short circuit and there is no current in that component.